# Flutter App IOS Xcode - seeing lage project logo before storyboard

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

When the app is loading, the initial time between the app window opening and the storyboard graphics loading I see what appears to be the app icon in full screen mode. This is clipping out of the horizontal boundaries and looks ugly. A second or so later the storyboard images load and it looks fine
How can I geet rid of that initial ugly icon? I'm assuming it's just a larger version of the app icon but it might be another version of the app image loading in from somewhere.

I have already changed in Info.plist:

From:

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>
```

To:

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
```

...without this change there would be a white screen before the storyboard loaded up.